# Drupal User ID Token

Tags: civimail, tokens

In civicrm contact summary we see Contact ID / User ID, where User ID refers to the drupal. I will need to customize a token for this User Id which I am supposed to use in civimail. Here in this link https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customized+%28and+Custom%29+Tokens ,drupal username can be fetched. But I need it for Drupal Id. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example calls `$result = civicrm_api('UFMatch', 'get', $params);` to get the Drupal user id that it passes to `user_load()` to get the rest of the  user info.

If you just want the id then it is the value being passed to `user_load()`:

```
$result['values'][0]['uf_id'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I got it immediately after posting the question. Sorry for not closing the question.